# OpenLayers: Why the console.log in browser can find the variable

Tags: javascript, webpack, gis, openlayers, webpack-encore

Im trying to `console.log(ol_map)` from browser but it give me an **undefined** error. The command works throuth the code.Why is that happening?

Im  using Symfony framework, with Webpack Encore for managing my assets.

[This is a screenshot from the browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KhsyK.png)

file :`map.js`

```
require('ol/ol.css');
require('../css/map.css');

import View from 'ol/view';
import VectorLayer from 'ol/layer/vector';
import TileLayer from 'ol/layer/tile';
import Map from 'ol/map';

var proj = require('ol/proj').default;
var ol_Map = require('ol/map').default;
//var ol_layer_Tile = require('ol/layer/tile').default;
var ol_source_OSM = require('ol/source/osm').default;
var ol_View = require('ol/view').default;
var coordinate = require('ol/coordinate').default;
//var VectorLayer = require('ol/layer/vector').default;
var VectorSource = require('ol/source/vector').default;
var GML = require('ol/format/gml').default;
var WFS = require('ol/format/wfs').default;

const ol_map = new Map({
    target: 'map',
    layers: [
        new TileLayer({
            source: new ol_source_OSM()
        }),
        //new VectorLayer({
        //    source: new VectorSource({
        //        format: new WFS(),
        //        url: 'http://environment.data.gov.uk/ds/wfs?SERVICE=WFS&INTERFACE=ENVIRONMENTWFS--864c72de-d465-11e4-855f-f0def148f590'
        //    })
        //})
    ],
    view: new ol_View({
        //cordinates in ESPG3857
        center: [-254382.41,7068896.29],
        zoom: 6
    })
});

console.log(ol_map);
```

file: map.html.twig

```
{% extends '::base.html.twig' %}
{# STYLESHEETS-------------------------------------------------- #}
{% block stylesheets %}
    {{ parent() }}
    <link href="{{ asset('build/map.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" />
    {#<link href="https://openlayers.org/en/v4.6.5/css/ol.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>#}
{% endblock %}
{# PAGE CONTENT-------------------------------------------------- #}
{% block title %}OpenLayers example{% endblock %}
{% block body %}
<body>
    <h2>My Map</h2>
    <div id="map" class="map"></div>
    <div class="arrow_box" id="popup-container" style="display: none;"></div>

    <script src="{{ asset('build/map.js') }}"></script>
</body>
{% endblock %}
{# JAVASCRIPTS-------------------------------------------------- #}
{% block javascript %}
    {{ parent() }}
    {#<script src="https://openlayers.org/en/v4.6.5/build/ol.js" type="text/javascript"></script>#}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: @Aurelien Yes, it doesn't make a difference, i get the same error.

Comment: Can you see the code(ol_map) through developer's tool? maybe webpack uglify the const variable as well?

Comment: yes i can see the code (you mean through the sources tab if i understood correct ?)

Comment: if webpack doesn't uglify the code then might be a scope problem. some codes wrap OL code I guess.

Comment: It's not exported, so that variable is local to the module.
If you want to access it in the browser console, you can put `window.ol_map = ol_map`

Comment: @dube  yes, you trick works, could you explain why is that happening please? (also post your answer as to mark it as answered)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the longer explanation of my comment above:

In Webpack, each [module](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/modules/) (file) imports and exports code. When the code is transpiled/packaged for the browser, each of those modules is enclosed into an [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures), making sure that internal code does not leak into other modules. This is very important, otherwise you would always have to make sure that you do not accidentally overwrite variables or functions from other modules.

I guess you mistakenly assumed, that your top-level module is different and that things are exported into the browser's top-level (window) scope. This is not the case!

The browser's console works on the main scope, where your internal variable `ol_map` is unknown. Of course that variable is somewhere, but it is somewhere *inside* some function (or even deeper, in a sub-sub...-function). Maybe your variable was also renamed by webpack (to make the code footprint smaller), so even when you add a debug breakpoint in your code, you might not immediately recognize your variable (but it is there!).

However, there are some global things, which you can access from inside the module: The `window` is the browser window object. It represents the global scope. For example when you write `var x = 'hello';` in your console, that variable `x` will become a property of `window`.

So by writing `window.ol_map = ol_map` in your code, you create a global variable, which you then can easily access in the browser and browser console.

Comment: thank you, your explanation is perfect, know i understand what going on.